# Error converting java map to ArrayList

Tags: java

I have successfully created a Java map and added values there. When I iterate over it as entrySet I get a similar output to the following:

```
key One=1
Key Two=2
```

Now instead of printing I want to write to a file using:

```
java.nio.file.Files.write(path, lines, options)
```

Now with the second parameter am setting it as:

```
new ArrayList(mapResult.entrySet())
```

but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Comment: Try keySet() instead of entrySet(). The former generates a collection of keys, whereas the latter generates a collection of entries

Comment: Why are you creating a non-generic `ArrayList` instead of an `ArrayList<SomeType>`? Something is rotten in the state of Denmark.

Comment: I know, I need key and value.

Comment: You have to convert the `Entry<K,V>` objects into strings.

Comment: @DavidConrad where and how to do the conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the entry set manually; Java won't do this for you.

Here's a sample of how you could do it:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : foo.entrySet()) {
    values.add(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Since the arguments contained in the collection are now something that can be converted to a `CharSequence`, `Files.write()` will be able to write to a particular file, without a `ClassCastException`.